# RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER crashes on some devices

Tags: android, action, picker, ringtone

the following code keeps crashing on some devices (instantly closes the ringtone picker dialog), on most of the devices it's working as expected. I didn't manage to find a common common denominator for the devices on which it crashes.

I'd be really really happy if someone could help me with this problem.
BTW: Logcat shows absolutely nothing. No errors.

This is the code

```
protected void chooseRingtone() {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, getString(R.string.choose_ringtone));

    if (ringtoneURI != null) {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, ringtoneURI);
    } 
    else {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, RINGTONE_RESULT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RINGTONE_RESULT) {
        ringtoneURI = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if (ringtoneURI != null) {
            try {
                ringtoneString = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneURI).getTitle(this);

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                ringtoneString = "unknown";
            }
            ringtone.setText(ringtoneString);
        }
    }

}
```

The Manifest looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk
android:maxSdkVersion="17"
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="8" 
/>
```

Comment: what is the crash log? please post some more info than "it crashes" ...

Comment: As mentioned above, there is absolutely nothing in logcat

Comment: can you tell which devices and android versions have this problem?